# Retrieve MVC 3 id Get Value in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

For my cancel link, which just basically takes the user back to the page they were at previously, I cannot figure out how to place the passed id value from the URL into the ActionLink

So say I'm here:
http://localhost:54636/Project/AddCodeSample/2

and at the bottom of the form, I have a cancel or back button, how can I get that id value from the URL and put it in the ActionLink

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Details", new { id = ??? })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

get the `id` from the `RouteData`

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Details",
                         new { id = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["ID"] })
```

Answer (score 2):

The ID should belong to your model:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Details", new { id = Model.Id })
```

Comment: No, the model is null... I didn't ask for a model value, I need the URL GET id value... Please remove your answer as it is not relevant...

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: No, my set up is a bit different, I have a higher level of security...

Comment: An MVC pattern purist would most certainly use a model. I'll leave this answer as another option.